# How to enable and disable clover plugin in gradle for root project

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, clover

We have multi project setup and am using clover plugin for code coverage of Java process. the subprojects are of Java and Scala. When I apply the clover plugin in build.gradle of root project and run the unit test, the clover plugin is also applied on subprojects which are in Scala. I dont want to manually update the build.gradle of all the subprojects

Do we have a way of enabling and disabling a plugin in gradle ? ( I am asking so that by default we can have the plugin as disabled. When we run the code coverage task at that time we can enable it )

Or is there any other way of solving it.

Note: I have enabled the clover plugin at the build.gradle at root level and in those subprojects which are written in Java

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?

Comment: I investigated it and found that as my firm had created wrapper on top of the plugin, the tasks were automatically applied to all the subprojects.                             

I created a task at root level which is called before the code coverage task is called, using this task, I  disabled the plugin in all subprojects which dont required it and it worked as expected